# Mocking a static method in a final class in Java/Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

If I have a class

```
public final class Application {
    public static String getName() { return "Bad App"; }
}
```

then how can I change the behavior and make `getName` return, say, `"Good App"`?
I need to mock it, so that classes under test receive an expected value.
In reality the static method makes some network call that I want to avoid.

I cannot rewrite the code of Application.

I am using Java 6, Maven, JUnit and Mockito.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you *have* to use a static call, rather than having a normal dependency that you can mock out?

Comment: You will need powermockito or powermock.

Comment: @JonSkeet I cannot change `Application` nor how it is used, or at least not in the near future.. I absolutely would if I could.

Comment: @almasshaikh any snippet to share?

Comment: What will you prefer power mock or power mockito? I think powermockito?

Comment: @almasshaikh both if possible, so that future visitors can choose a better one for them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it using powermockito as below:

Say this is your class with static method:

```
public final class MyStaticClass {
    public static String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And you want to mock out helloWorld method, and let it return "Hi World" instead while testing. You could do the following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyStaticClass.class})
public class PowerMockItoTest {
    @Test
    public void mockStaticClassTest() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyStaticClass.class);
        final String mockedResult = "Hi World";
        Mockito.when(MyStaticClass.helloWorld()).thenReturn(mockedResult);
        Assert.assertEquals(AStaticClass.helloWorld(), mockedResult);
    }
}
```

If you want to use PowerMock, you could do it as below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyStaticClass.class})
public class PowerMockTest {
    @Test
    public void testRegisterService() throws Exception {   
        PowerMock.mockStatic(MyStaticClass.class);
        final String mockedResult = "Hi World";
        expect(MyStaticClass.helloWorld()).andReturn(mockedResult);
        replay(MyStaticClass.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(AStaticClass.helloWorld(), mockedResult);
        verify(MyStaticClass.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah you see. `MyStaticClass` has to be `final`.

Comment: Thats fine with both the approaches.

Comment: Not able to Mock Inet4Address.getLocalHost() using powerMock and EasyMock